# Get window handle on which mouse button was clicked

Tags: c++, windows, mouse, hook

Hey, I'm using Windows Hook, I installed the mouse hook, system-wide and its working perfectly. Now there is a problem, I need to the get window handle on which the mouse was clicked.. How do I do that? Does the Mouse hook event passes us that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `WH_MOUSE_LL`, you're making a low-level mouse hook, which actually receives a pointer to a [`MSLLHOOKSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644970%28VS.85%29.aspx) that doesn't have an `hwnd` member.

You need to set a normal mouse hook using `WH_MOUSE`; you'll then get a pointer to the [`MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644968%28VS.85%29.aspx) that you're expecting..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558.aspx) function to get the window under a given location.

Comment: But what if the user changed the window quickly? I may get the wrong handle right?

Comment: If you call it inside the mouse hook, I don't think so.

Comment: The mouse hook event also gives us the MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT, but its hwnd value is null, but its NULL, do you know why?

Comment: did you install a low level mouse hook, or a simple mouse hook ?

Comment: I did SetWindowsHookEx, which one is that?

Comment: @manzoor: it's the same call for the two types of hook, only the value of the idHook parameter change. what i want to know is whether you used WH_MOUSE_LL or WH_MOUSE ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set a [WH_MOUSE hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx), your [MouseProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988%28VS.85%29.aspx) receives a pointer to a [MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644968%28VS.85%29.aspx). Since the hwnd member is NULL, you could try using [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the pt member of the struct.  The pt member is the coordinate at the time the message was created.